# How can i search user`s facebook timeline for a specific post using keywork/post title in 2.5 api?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an facebook web app with [user_posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_posts) permission and i want to search user`s timeline for a specific post based on post title/keyword filled by user in a text box.

The app can only request for v2.5 api of facebook.
So please answer as per v2.5 api recommendation.

Comment: There is no API .You need to download all posts and do the search yourself.

Comment: can you give some links where it is written.

Comment: No. Facebook documentation explains what you can do. We don't have a list of everything you can't do